# How to approximate the cumulative distribution function of the normal by a product of functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose, there are $n$ vectors $\mathbf{X}_1$, $\mathbf{X}_2 \ldots \mathbf{X}_n$ of unequal lengths which can be combined to a new vector as
$$ \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X}_1 & \mathbf{X}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{X}_n
\end{bmatrix} $$
For each $\mathbf{X}_i$, there is a corresponding vector $\mathbf{A}_i$ such that
$$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}_1 & \mathbf{A}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{A}_n
\end{bmatrix} $$
It follows that one can write,
$$ \mathbf{A}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{X} = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{A}_i^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{X}_i $$
Also, let $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ be a corresponding block diagonal matrix,
$$\mathbf{\Lambda} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\Lambda}_1 & 0  & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \mathbf{\Lambda}_2  & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0  & \cdots & \mathbf{\Lambda}_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
It again follows that one can write,
$$ \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{X}
= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Lambda}_i^{-1}\mathbf{X}_i $$
For an application, we are required to calculate the cumulative distribution function of the normal $\mathbf{\Phi} \left( \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{X} \left[k + \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{X}\right]^{-1/2} \right)$ where $k$ is a constant. Due to constraints (not mentioned here), we have to *approximate* the cdf as product of function of $\mathbf{X}_i$'s, that is, we want to find a function $f$ such that
$$ \mathbf{\Phi} \left( \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{X} \left[k + \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{X}\right]^{-1/2} \right)
\approx \prod_{i=1}^{n}f\left( \mathbf{X}_i, \mathbf{A}_i, \mathbf{\Lambda}_i \right) $$
Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume $\Lambda_i$ are positive definite so the denominator is always defined. Then without loss of generality you can rescale variables so the left-hand side is $\Phi\left(\cfrac{a^Tx}{\sqrt{1+\|x\|^2}}\right)$. But I don't think the separable form you are looking for will be a good approximation to the function, except possibly in a small region.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{\Lambda}_i$'s are positive semi-definite. I am more interested in the region where $\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{X} \left[k + \mathbf{X}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{X}\right]^{-1/2}$ is close to $0$.